# Check if list item is repeated comparing to start date

Tags: c++

I have a list of objects which has some properties.

```
class Accounts
{
    long id;
    CString account;
    CTime start;
    CTime end;
};
```

To show it better it looks like something like this:

```
ID      Account     Start       End
-----------------------------------------
1       Bob         23-Jun-20   23-Jun-20
2       Sally       23-Jun-20   23-Jun-20
3       Mike        23-Nov-20   29-Nov-20
4       Sally       20-Dec-20   25-Dec-20
```

I need to get IDs of list entries that are older than 4 months (from now). But if the Account has entry which is not older than 4 months it should not be returned.

For example item with ID 1 should be returned because it is older than 4 months and has no instances in further list. Item with ID 2 should not be returned because it repeats in an instance which is not 4 months old (item with ID 4). And of course item with ID 3 should not be returned because it is not 4 months old.

My idea is to double loop the list and check if the account repeats.. Then to compare date and according to that return value in another list.

```
std::list<Accounts> accountsList;
std::list<long> expiredAccounts;
CTime ctNow = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

for(auto &it1 : accountsList)
{
    for(auto &it2 : cServiceNumberDetails)
    {
        CTimeSpan ts = ctNow - it.start;
        long long tsDays = ts.GetDays(); //get number of day difference
        CString account = it1.account;
        
        if((tsDays > 120) && it2.account == account && it1.start < it2.start)
        {
           expiredAccounts.push_back(it1.id); 
        }
    }
}
```

This might work (I'm not sure), but is there more efficient way of doing this because I may have a list with hundreds of thousands of elements and looping two times over it is not the best solution probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single loop you can re-arrange your data to find out which account is active/inactive. Also arrange all IDs in a list for same account.

Sample below (`is_active` is just a function or logic to determine account is active and not expired, for example : start < 120 in your case):

```
std::map<string, bool> accountStatus;
std::map<string, std::list<long>> idsForAccount;
for (const auto& it : accountsList) 
{
    accountStatus[it.account] = accountStatus[it.account] or is_active(it);
    idsForAccount[it.account].push_back(it.id);
}
```

Now in another loop extract all accountIDs if account is expired.

```
std::list<long> expiredAccounts;
for (const auto& it : accountStatus) 
{
    if (not it.second) // If account is not active add all ID  
    {
        expiredAccounts.assign(idsForAccount[it.first].begin(), idsForAccount[it.first].end());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this won't work because you cannot use [] on class instance. Like in the first loop: `accountStatus[it.account]` .. but thx for help

Comment: that operator is on map named accountStatus.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the list sorted by date, inserting into the list using binary search.

If by not repeated, you mean all fields have to be unique, then you can start at the old side checking elements that have the same date for duplicates. Once you get to the elements less than 4 months old, stop checking whether you want to remove old items from the list.

Only one loop required to perform this check in that case.

Edit: Actually I take this back.. binary search doesn't work so well with lists. But still, could step through list and add it in the correct location, perhaps using a skip list to jump to the right place faster.